# ORMLite trying to load field without @DatabaseField annotation

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have 2 classes like following:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "condicao_ambiental")
public class CondicaoAmbiental {
    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
    private Date dataCriacao;
    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "idUsuario", foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Usuario usuario;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "usuario")
public class Usuario {
    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "idCliente")
    private Cliente cliente;
    @DatabaseField
    private String nome;
    @DatabaseField
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    ...
}
```

The annotations used in these classes are from `Lombok`, `Retrofit2` and `OrmLite5`

When I make a query to list `CondicaoAmbiental` this error is presented:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'senha' from the Android sqlite cursor, not in:[id, idCliente, nome, tipoSindicato, dataCadastro, diasTeste]
```

But the column `senha` is not annotated as field.

When I make a query to list `Usuario`, everything runs OK and the list is loaded.
If I remove the `foreignAutoRefresh=true` from field `usuario`, no error occurs.

Could someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Any chance you have an out-of-date ormlite.txt config file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've never configured such file

Comment: Did the field _used_ to be marked as a `@DatabaseField`?  ORMlite is specifically not supposed to chose unlabeled fields.  It makes me wonder if something needs to be recompiled or a config file re-generated.

Comment: Yes, it was. I've put the foreignAutoRefresh=true back and it's working now. Probably because I've been cleaning and building the project several times these past days. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray), the solution is just recompile the project so the ORMLite can re-generate the config file.